# Pyrocms image handling through tag

Tags: image, codeigniter, attributes, pyrocms

I have created a page in pyrocms CP. I am facing a problem im using this tag to display my image.

```
{{ theme:image file="service.jpg" }}
```

I know the alternative though

```
echo Asset::img('service.jpg','alt text',array('width'=>200 ,'height'=>200));
```

But the second instruction is not working in the page created in control panel. I need to set the attributes of image using the first instruction. I found an alternative using css in design but it is not working either. How to solve it.

Comment: Have you create page through admin panel......???

Comment: yes i have created page through Control Panel

Comment: You can insert images through editor...why you want to insert image like this

Comment: i have no idea how to use it can you provide an example or tutorial link

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you can not use php when you are creating a page from pyro admin page.
doese this work for you?
`{{theme:image file="service.jpg" alt="foo" title="bar"}}`